# Android Programming HtmlUnit

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I am using httpclient on android, and I have added all the external jars to my classpath. However, when I startup eclipse it gave me java heap space errors, so I went in the .ini file and I "upped" the numbers, and it worked. However, when I try to start the application on my android emulator it wil not start, and when I try to load it on my phone it says it cannot be installed even though I have unliscenced sources turned on, on my phone. Is it possible that i have "too many" .jar files in my android project? Also I get errors in my project when it builds the workspace, please look bellow

Thanks so much!

```
[2011-09-05 22:30:39 - AndroidTest] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an      
anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xalan.lib.sql.SecuritySupport12$8) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

Answer (score 2):

HttpClient is built-in to Android Framework. You don't need to add another .jar file to use HttpClient.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html

Comment: Im still looking at httpclient, thanks. Turns out I was actually using htmlunit in my program. I feel like an idiot :P sorry. but I am looking into this apache library